# Event handling within the JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created some kind of JavaScript object with the such design pattern:

```
var MyObject = (function(){

    var element;
    var config = {
        // Defaults...
    };

    function initialize(id, options){
        element = $(id);
        config = $.extend(config, options);
    }

    function method(){
        // Some code...
    }

    element.on('click', function(){
        // Some actions when clicked on element...
    });

    return {
        initialize: initialize,
        // Other public methods...
    };

})();
```

And that's how object is initialized:

```
MyObject.initialize('#someId');
```

Script works great, however an error occurs, when I try to add some events for `element`.
As I realized, an anonymous function `(function(){ ... })();` is executed immediatelly, but initialization of variable `element`comes after.

So, how can I implement an event handling exactly for this JavaScript object pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: Attach the event in the `initialize` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling `on` inside the `initialize` function. Since the outer function is executing immediately (as you realized yourself), `element` is `undefined`. So you should only be calling `on` on it, after the variable has been defined:

```
function initialize(id, options){
    element = $(id);
    element.on('click', function() {
        ...
    });   

    config = $.extend(config, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stick it in the initialize method.

```
function initialize(id, options){
    element = $(id);
    config = $.extend(config, options);


    element.on('click', function(){
        // Some actions when clicked on element...
    });
}
```